# Configuring data source - tomee.xml, persistence.xml

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, apache-tomee

I'm doing some EJB with JPA project that maps/persists some entities to mysql database.
I have defined persistence unit in persistence.xml like this:

```
  <persistence-unit name="MyAppPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>MyAppDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
      <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="mysql" />
      <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Tool=INFO" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

Then, in tomee/conf/tomee.xml file i have defined data source like this:

```
<Resource id="MyAppDS" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver          com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl             jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/MyAppDB
    UserName            root
    Password            123
    JtaManaged          true
    DefaultAutoCommit   false
</Resource>
```

All this works fine, i create MyApp.jar, deploy it to TomEE server, test it and i get mysql tables in database.
My question is "Is there any other place where I could define data source resource?" 
Or it has to be in tomee/conf/tomee.xml file?
Can it be defined somewhere inside application structure, in some xml file, and deployed inside apps jar file to server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the whole point of a JNDI data source, to externalize it outside of your application, so you can modify it without recompiling or repackaging. So it is better to leave it this way.

For testing purpose, some EE server such as JBoss (Wildfly) let you define this in your project.

Comment: I understand. But, lets say I know database name, username and password of MySQL database installed on some other PC, and that I just need to copy/deploy  MyApp.jar to tomee/webapps folder on that PC and run it. Thats why I would like to specify datasource inside application structure.

Comment: Not just for testing purpose - having this defined at server level will cause any additional war deployed to reinstantiate those same resources again. With big connection pools, you could quickly exhaust resources. At least with a context.xml file we can restrict that in the `conf/Catalina/localhost/contextname.xml`. It is important to keep it out of your source code (outside of your svn tree) as it has passwords, but we still need the per application (per war) configuration.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a bit late to answer this, You can in tomee place the resource definition in `WEB-INF/resources.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to set the tomee.xml. If you are using Eclipse, you must copy the tomee.xml into the servers configuration/Tomee to get recognize it into the web project, otherwise you will get troubles.