# TomEE ignores resource configuration when it can't find MySQL driver classes

Tags: apache-tomee

I made reference to [Configuring data source - tomee.xml, persistence.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500042/configuring-data-source-tomee-xml-persistence-xml). My `persistence.xml` is exactly as in the above except for the persistence unit name and jta datasource name

My `tomee.xml` is also similar

```
<Resource id="****DB" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    UserName ××××
    Password ××××
JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://localhost/××××
JtaManaged true
connectionProperties zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull;useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=UTF-8
</Resource>
```

I also verified by enumerating `em.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties()` and found that `Platform:OpenJPA JDBC Edition: MySQL Database`.

But when I tried doing `em.createNamedQuery`... I got `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found`.  So it seems OpenJPA uses the default hsqldb in spite of the settings.

The sql statement in the server log was copy-and-pasted to phpmyadmin and worked. I even deleted the `connectionProperties` in `tomee.xml` but still did not work. Why?

Comment: Any exception? When you look into .war archive, in which directory is persistence.xml?

Comment: EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: user lacks privilege or object not found; org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found; java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found; org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found:

Comment: from jar tvf: WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

My fault: mysql-connector-java.jar is not in tomee/lib folder.  But I think tomee should complain instead of falling back to using hsqldb.